# Is there a simple way to create an initialized array?

Tags: c#

I want to create an int[n] array of unique numbers:

```
int[] result = new int[24];

for(int i = 0; i<24; i++)
    result[i] = 1;

return result;
```

Is there a shorter way to accomplish this. May be something like this:

```
return (from i in new int[24] 
        select 1).ToArray();
```

But not as ugly as this.

Comment: i.e. you want to create an array initialized with some number different from 0?

Comment: Did none of the answers on your other questions answer those?

Comment: Oh, and are we talking about random or sequential numbers?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<24; i++) 
                result[i] = 1; 

In this code you set all the numbers to 1. This is not unique but just initialized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure in what way making them all "1" makes them unique, but this will do the equivalent to your code:

```
return Enumerable.Repeat(1, 24).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for flagging that this is only the equivalent to the example, not to what it seems like the OP is asking for. in that sense, it might be added that `Enumerable.Range(0, 24).ToArray();` *might* be what OP is looking for, if we're allowed to assume a typo in both examples.

Comment: haha,just now I misunderstood OP's question and give the Enumerable.Range answer. He says "result[i] = 1" not "result[i] = i";

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted doesn't seem to match the title of the question, but this will do the same as your snippet:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(1, 24).ToArray()
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. The question should be: Is there a simple way to create an array filled with a constant?